# jQuery - addClass ACTIVE--> set timeout --> cycle

Tags: jquery

I have 5 elements with same class
and at page-load the first div is active:

```
<div id="div-1" class="cssClass active"></div>
<div id="div-2" class="cssClass"></div>
<div id="div-3" class="cssClass"></div>
<div id="div-4" class="cssClass"></div>
<div id="div-5" class="cssClass"></div>
```

How to add a timeout before jQuery pass the active class to the second div and so on, reaching the last div and restart with the first div? and so on... 
(I would like to avoid the use of the jQuery Cycle plugin. Is there something simpler in a couple of lines?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write your own cycle plugin like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.cycle = function(timeout, cls) {
        var l = this.length,
            current = 0,
            prev = -1,
            elements = this;

        function next() {
            elements.eq(prev).removeClass(cls);
            // or just `elements.removeClass(cls);`
            elements.eq(current).addClass(cls);
            prev = current;
            current = (current + 1) % l; // modulo for wrap around
            setTimeout(next, timeout);
        }
        setTimeout(next, timeout);
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

and use it like this:

```
$('div').cycle(2000, 'active');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/KMgxg/)

**Update:** Overlooked that the first div is already `active`. You can make the plugin detect the already active div by adding:

```
if(this.filter('.' + cls).length > 0) {
    current = this.index(this.filter('.' + cls)[0]) + 1;
    prev = current - 1 ;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/KMgxg/1/)

You could also make the function accept an index where to start....

Comment: @Alnitak: Oops, thanks :) That is from too much playing around ;)

Comment: @Felix: True, jQuery is so much fun! Thanks a lot for this great solution! I'm playing around with it too :) Kling you are a king! ...Where is the '+100' button? :)

Comment: @Felix kling--> argh! I have problems to stop the above on hover **if THIS CONTAINER DIV have class 'stop'**... may you help please?! How can i stop cycle on hover and restart on mouseout?

Comment: @roXon: Ok. I have created "something" but I don't know whether it is a good approach. You can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/KMgxg/3/

Comment: @Felix --> Carissimo Felix, grazie x il tuo tempo e l'aiuto! here is a malfunctioning demo :) [DEMO](http://roko.x10.mx/rox_gallery/) I have now problems with a false load and after click --> messy 'active' buttons :(

Comment: @roXon: Thanks for mentioning me in the comments of your code :D I assume you also want to pause the animation when hovering over a photo, right? You can do so by just keeping a reference to the cycled elements. E.g. `var $nav = $('.xNav').cycle(SlidePause, 'btnActive'); $('#xGallery').hover(function(){ $nav.cycle('stop')}, function(){ $nav.cycle('start')})`. I don't understand your other problem though. But I'm not saying that the code as I posted it works perfect, so you might still have to tweak a little ;) Happy coding!

Comment: @roXon: It seems to get messed up when you click one of the buttons to jump directly to an image. You can try using `elements.removeClass(cls);` instead of `elements.eq(prev).removeClass(cls);` and maybe you'd have to add a method set the current index of the cycle plugin. So, instead of jumping to an image with your own code, pass an index to the plugin and let it perform the jump. It would be nice if you could create a http://jsfiddle.net demo with your code, so that I could play a bit.

Comment: @Felix -- Thank you for your clarifications. I'll make a total remake of all the codes + learning your great coding syntax! Now is all messed a bit (a lot) cause auto-sscroll was not in my first plan. GRAZIE MILLE! Felix

Comment: @Felix -- Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DJUcQ/) Good playing! i go to smash my head onto the wall :D and go to make changes too!

Comment: @Felix -- on JSfiddle the all together looks slightly different from the original (the 'i' is jumping all around...) but the code is  here! Thanks in advance!

Comment: @roXon: Ok. I think I got it to work the way you want it to. I had to make some changes to the plugin. Just have a look at it (everything after the `AUTO-SLIDE` comment): http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/DJUcQ/2/ Also adding the "start detection" code from my post fixed the strange loading problem (if that was what you meant...)

Comment: @Felix ++ this is great! Thanks so much! May you borrow me just a piece of your brain ... for a life-time?! :D

Comment: @roXon: Very nice :) Thanks for the credits :) (but I hope you will still improve on my code, I'm sure there are a lot of things to tweak ;))

Comment: @roXon: If you don't mind, I might refer to that on my own website as well (if I'm going to finish it one day ;)).

Comment: @Felix Of course I will! I still have to make lot of researches about jQuery, C, javascript, php and so on. I'm still studying it! (can't wait to become a master like you! To help others as well!) CIAO

Comment: @roXon: I'm even thinking if I should extend this plugin a little bit, maybe make it more robust and add some more options.... well I will let you know if I do anything with it (currently I'm too busy to take care of fun free time projects)... good work and happy coding!

Comment: @Felix --> you are welcome! (You can see my e-mail in my profile I suppose...) When you'll have some free fun time let me know! (I readed this now -- you can add it to your web! I'm getting soon a new web address so I'll transfer soon all there! I'll make you know! drop me some e-mail)

Answer (score 2):

```
function changeClass() {
    if ($(".active").next(".cssClass").length > 0) {
        $(".active").removeClass("active").next(".cssClass").addClass("active");
    }
    else {
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(".cssClass").first().addClass("active");
    }
    setTimeout(changeClass, 1000); // 1000ms = 1sec
}
```

And then just call `changeClass()` once to get the ball rolling.

*edit:* updated with something that should actually work. (again)

Comment: Pretty good, but I'd take `changeClass()`  out of a string; just pass the reference.

Comment: Nice, not sure if it will loop back to `div-1` after `div-5` though?

Comment: Yeh was just wondering, once `.next()` gets to the end if it would just stop? Might need to check `.next().length` and make it use `.first()` instead, if `.next().length` is `0`.

Comment: Passing a string to `setTimeout` is not good. Pass a function reference.

Comment: So just `setTimeout(changeClass(), 1000)`?

Comment: @Chris: No, this would call the function. It would be `setTimeout(changeClass, 1000)` (without the parenthesis).

Answer (score 2):

This should do it. Explanation in comments.

```
function moveClass() {
   if ($('.active:first').next()) {
      $('.active:first')
          .removeClass('active') //remove the current class
          .next() //move to the next
          .addClass('active'); // add the class to the next div
   } else {
      $('.active').removeClass('active');
      $('.cssClass:first').addClass('active'); //move to the first of the lot if there is no more next()
   }

}

$('.cssClass:first').addClass('active');
setInterval(moveClass, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my example :).

http://jsfiddle.net/8ByyN/

Answer (score 1):

First try.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js">

</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .active
    {
        font-weight:bold;    
    }
</style>




<div id="div-1" class="cssClass active">Div 1</div>
<div id="div-2" class="cssClass">Div 2</div>
<div id="div-3" class="cssClass">Div 3</div>
<div id="div-4" class="cssClass">Div 4</div>
<div id="div-5" class="cssClass">Div 5</div>

<button onclick="int=window.clearInterval(int)">Stop</button>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function toggleActive() {

        if ($(".cssClass:last").hasClass("active")) {
            console.warn("last element reached");
            $(".cssClass:last").toggleClass("active");
            $(".cssClass:first").toggleClass("active");
        }
        else {
            $(".active").first().toggleClass("active").next().addClass("active");
        }

    }
     var int;
    $(function () {

        int= self.setInterval("toggleActive()", 1000);

    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps.